# Push goes through, but does not deploy changes?

Tags: git, bitbucket, egit

So this is more of a newbie conceptual question. At my internship, we use egit on eclipse and our repositories are hosted on bitbucket. When I merge my working branch with their dev branch or whatever, I see I get merge confliccts, however, when I push, I see on egit that it gives me feedback that my push has been accepted and my updates have been pushed to the dev branch. However, none of the changes I see are deployed on the actual repository when I look online, even though it says push accepted. Why would egit not throw me an error on the push if there are merge conflicts that obviously aren't being pushed?

Comment: `git push` never does any merging. I know nothing about how egit *uses* `git push`, but it's worth considering that `git merge` is not related in any way to `git push`. Meanwhile the opposite of push is not pull, but rather fetch: `git pull` runs *two* commands, namely `git fetch` and then (by default) `git merge`. That's why pulls merge: because pull *means* "fetch (opposite of push), then merge" but push just means "push (opposite of fetch)"—no "merge".

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried doing this, but my guess is that what is happening is that you are pushing the previously committed code that doesn't have any merge conflicts.

A merge conflict makes changes to the repo and until the conflict is resolved and you do a new commit, those changes would not be able to be pushed.

I would just make sure to always resolve your merge conflicts before you do anything else.

Hope that helps.